# Weird behavior with styles in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I can't understand why happens this. I have a simple application in WPF. This application have a window, and in the App.xaml have defined one style, that changes the style of all the buttons:

```
<Application x:Class="PruebasDesk.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This works fine, all the buttons get the style. Now, here is the problem. If instead of using the StartupUri attribute to start the application, I start it with using the OnStartup method:

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win1 = new Window1();
            win1.Show();
        }
    }
```

The buttons of the application don't get applied the button style defined at App.xaml. But... if I add another style to the App.xaml, like this:

```
<Application x:Class="PruebasDesk.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="75"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="180"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then the buttons get the style applied!!! This seems really weird to me. Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Comment: See here- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0d3fd0d8-ea9a-47d9-9e10-89db8b0243c3/

Comment: The linik from RichardOD indicates it is a bug and you are already found the fix.   Not really the question but I noticed a border in App has a differenent effect than border on the page regarding Tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you with certainty why that behavior occurs but I can tell you that best practices would have steered you away from using `App.xaml` in that fashion.  What I believe to be a better practice is to only merge in your resource dictionaries in app.xaml.  Storing the actual styles is a good way to create an unmanageable project.

Create a new ResourceDictionary file and add those styles.  Merge the dictionaries in as you add more of them.

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Common.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

Alternatively, you could hook into the event `Startup` (app.xaml: `Startup="App_Startup"`) and not override `OnStartup`.  This will work with the App.xaml resource setup you have defined.   It is likely a timing issue.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it's a bug. As you pointed out, resource dictionaries avoids the problem, but when you are trying some proof of concept and adding some style quickly, this bug can drive you crazy :)  ... +1 to RichardOD for the link.